# Converting "string" dates with errors to normal dates or NULL

Tags: postgresql

I have an old table containing dates stored as strings like '20191001'.
I have created a new field of type DATE and I try to recover the old dates in the new field :

```
UPDATE extcg SET newdate=to_date(olddate,'yyyymmdd');
```

The problem is that some of these dates are invalid (20190231). I would like to skip the conversion for these dates and leave the new field NULL.

Is there a way to exclude these in a WHERE statement ?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966274/how-to-handle-to-date-exceptions-in-a-select-statment-to-ignore-those-rows

Comment: Perfect answer, I wonder why I didn't find that question. Thank you.

Comment: i was using Google with `postgresql to_date skip errors`, and it was the first link....  

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, here is a function that does the job :

```
CREATE FUNCTION to_date_or_null(ADate TEXT, AFormat TEXT) RETURNS DATE AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN to_date(ADate,AFormat);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

I used it this way :

```
UPDATE extcg SET newdate=to_date_or_null(olddate,'yyyymmdd');
```

And thanks to @Luuk for mastering Google searches ;)